# Открыть и ввести что-либо в консольное приложение через BAT

Tags: bat

У меня есть простенькое **консольное** приложение, которое требует **ввода целого числа** после запуска для дальнейшей его обработки. Мне нужно запустить это приложение через **bat** и после этого **ввести в него** это целое число.

---

*Сейчас я использую `start /B C:/console_app.exe`, для того чтобы не открывать новых окон cmd. Также я не могу использовать запуск этой программы с параметрами.*

Comment: На чём написано консольное приложение? Win32-API используется? Если да, то параметры принимает функция `GetCommandLine()`. То-есть вам нужно в первую очередь предусмотреть в программе приём параметров, а потом уже передавать их любым удобным способом, хоть батником.

Answer (score 0):

Палка

```
echo ЧИСЛО | C:\console_app.exe
```

Или JScript

```
echo var shell=WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)^;> %TEMP%\temp.js
echo shell.Run^("C:/console_app.exe"^)^;>> %TEMP%\temp.js
echo WScript.Sleep^(100^)^;>> %TEMP%\temp.js
echo shell.AppActivate^("console_app.exe"^)^;>> %TEMP%\temp.js
echo WScript.Sleep^(ВРЕМЯ_КОТОРОЕ_НУЖНО_ПОДОЖДАТЬ^)^;>> %TEMP%\temp.js
echo shell.SendKeys^("ЧИСЛО~"^)^;>> %TEMP%\temp.js

cscript /nologo %TEMP%\temp.js

del %TEMP%\temp.js
```

ВРЕМЯ_КОТОРОЕ_НУЖНО_ПОДОЖДАТЬ и ЧИСЛО заменить на реальные значения, НЕ ТРОГАЯ остальные символы!

Comment: Да, это работает. Но мне не подходит. Я забыл уточнить в вопросе, что мне нужно ввести это число через некоторый промежуток времени после запуска...

Comment: Я добавил в свой ответ 2й способ.